# Problem with customize headline

Tags: beamer

I have in my slides the name of section and subsection, but I would like to have only name of the section. How can I do it?

```
\documentclass[11pt,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>{

  \usetheme{Warsaw}  
  \usecolortheme[named=OliveGreen]{structure}
  \useoutertheme{shadow}

   \setbeamercovered{transparent}

   \setbeamercolor{block title example}{fg=white,bg=Blue}
   \setbeamercolor{block body example}{fg=black,bg=Blue!10} 
   \setbeamercolor{postit}{fg=black,bg=OliveGreen!20}
   \setbeamercolor{postit2}{fg=yellow,bg=OliveGreen}
}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The `Warsaw` theme (as it's the one theme not commented out I assume you're using this one) seems to print the contents of `\frametitle` and (if it's present). `\framesubtitle`.  So to generate a frame with just one line in the section you can simply remove the `\framesubtitle{Foo}` command for that frame.  If this isn't of use, please consider extending your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you question, you want to remove the subsection navigation. This can be done by commenting the corresponding line in the headline definition:

```
\documentclass[11pt,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>{
    \usetheme{Warsaw}  
    \usecolortheme[named=OliveGreen]{structure}
    \useoutertheme{shadow}

    \setbeamercovered{transparent}

    \setbeamercolor{block title example}{fg=white,bg=Blue}
    \setbeamercolor{block body example}{fg=black,bg=Blue!10} 
    \setbeamercolor{postit}{fg=black,bg=OliveGreen!20}
    \setbeamercolor{postit2}{fg=yellow,bg=OliveGreen}
}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{section in head/foot}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{.5\paperwidth}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{subsection in head/foot}%
%    \insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{.5\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]